# How to - easy filter cakephp table

Tags: php, cakephp, find, action, cakephp-2.3

i'm trying to develop an very easy Filter over a table in a cakephp app.
I want to filter over the columns via find or something else.
The field are filled with text. I think i set an checkbox an the filter is find all by conditions.

How do i setup an radio-button where i can handle an condition for the find functon?

Marcus

Comment: Please supply a more specific question with examples of what you've tried and are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes i can supply more. I have one table with addresses an some other columns like event(monday,... ,sunday), time (8o'clock pm). Now i want to filter with an checkbox click on it. I want to have an ckeckbox for monday e.q.. If i click this i get all entry where monday in the event column is. Why is it not an real question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean "filters" on the paginated index view?

You are probably looking for sth like the search plugin: https://github.com/cakedc/search

It can handle this sort of thing very easily and without much configuration or coding.